# Send email after the end of a DTS job

Tags: email, sql-server-2000, dts

I need to send an email by the end of my DTS without affecting the running jobs.

I mean that I don't want to put the send email function like in the end of the DTS, but my idea is to send and email once the last table in my DTS gets updated (without using a trigger that will affect the DTS in case of EXHANGE problems)

I'm thinking about the last modification in the last table in my DTS to send an e-mail but I really don't know how to verify a last modification...

Also, I have a log file where it reports that the steps are in success, I think to read from it ?

Any suggestions ? Help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made it by my self finally.

I created a table and made an insert in it after some steps of the execution of my DTS. It doesn't seem to affect anything right now.

An email is sent lately by reading from this table.

"Bon début de semaine :)"